# How to update multiple rows in one column

Tags: c#, datagridview

I have a column named status, and every row has a status of 1, i want to update it to 2. I can't seem to do multiple updates

Here's what I've tried

```
if (MessageBox.Show("Do you want to commit this?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Warning) == DialogResult.Yes)
{
    int i = 0;

    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDisplay.Rows)
    {
        cn.Open();

        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@" UPDATE CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1 SET Status = 2 WHERE DR#='" + dgvDisplay.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'", cn);

        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        cn.Close();

        i++;
    }        

    MessageBox.Show("Your status has been updated!");
    //cn.Close();
}
```

When I run it, it gave an error on the line

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@" update CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1 set Status = 2 WHERE DR#='" + dgvDisplay.SelectedRows[i].Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "'", cn);
```

with a message of:

> Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection

Comment: You should almost certainly be populating a `DataTable` and binding it to the grid, then modifying each row in that `DataTable`, then saving all the changes in a single batch using a data adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Your index is out of range, because you are doing it foreach row, while you are only checking the selected rows.
Do `foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDisplay.SelectedRows` instead.
Also use parameter to prevent SQL injections, so:

```
    foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgvDisplay.SelectedRows)
    {
         cn.Open();

         SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@" UPDATE CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1 SET Status = 2 WHERE DR#=@cellValue", cn);

         cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cellValue", row.Cells[1].Value.ToString());
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
         cn.Close();

     }
```

Comment: The SelectionMode in my datagridview is on FullRowSelect. Is it still applicable to the code you shared?

Comment: Yes, matter of fact, your SelectionMode needs to be FullRowSelect for this to work

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend just executing one of the Sql commands :

- Update All data in the Status Column with no conditions :

`string cmd = "Update CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1 set Status = 2";`

or

- Update data with a condition :
   `string cmd = "Update CCSDD_StoreDirectDelivery1 set Status = 2 where Status = 1";`

Comment: This will update the whole column Status as 2. Not the selected rows